# Specifics of hardware

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

On the MacBook Pro with Retina display, what is the specific screen they use, (any idea on model number), or is it their own manufacture?

Comment: If it helps you, my Mid-2014 MBP w/ Retina Display came with a 13.3-inch (2560 x 1600) Intel Iris 1536 MB built in.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to [this site to identify which Mac](https://www.ifixit.com/Info/ID-your-Mac) you're using (just keep answering the questions until you get to the end), it will ultimately make suggestions for parts. If you click on the relevant part, it will tell you the Apple Part Number near the price.